# Passing API response data from Redux state to component props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I'm quite new to Redux, and I'm trying to dispatch and async action and return the new state as updated by the response data.

Here is where I'm at:

**App.js** (container component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

// import all actionCreators
import * as actions from '../actions/actionCreators'

// import component to pass props to
import Main from './Main'

const mapStateToProps = (state, { params, location, users }) => {
   const rootPage = params.rootPage || '';
   return {
      users,
      rootPage
   }
}

const App = connect(
   mapStateToProps,
   actions
)(Main);

export default App;
```

**Action Creator**

```
export const fetchRemoteData = (endpoint) => (dispatch, getState) => {
   return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(
      response =>
         dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_REMOTE_DATA_SUCCESS',
            endpoint,
            response
         })
      )
}
```

**Component**

```
export default class Users extends Component {
   componentDidMount() {
      console.log('Component Mounted!')
      this.props.fetchRemoteData('users')
   }
   render() {
      const {users} = this.props
      console.log(users)
      const {rootPage} = this.props;
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Users Page</h1>
            <p>This is the Users page and an example of how your app is working correctly</p>
            <p>rootPage: {rootPage}</p>
            {/*users.map(user =>
               <p>{user.name}</p>
            )*/}
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

When I look in React Dev Tools, the `users` object isn't there, even though it IS in my global state object.

This made me think I maybe haven't mapped it to my container component correctly, but I can't see what's wrong with this either...

**Root Reducer**

```
// import individual reducers
import users from './users'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   users,
   routing: routerReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

Is it something to do with the fact that my API call is made in `componentDidMount`, and my component hasn't registered the change made to the redux state after the response has been received?

Any help appreciated.

---

### UPDATE:

I forgot to include `users: state.users` in my `mapStateToProps` function. Now the `users` object is in my props, but it still doesn't contain the state...

---

**Main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export default class Main extends Component {
   render() {

      return (
         <div className='container'>
            <h2>Main.js (wrapped by App.js)</h2>
            <hr />
            <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
            {' | '}
            <Link to='/users'>Users</Link>
            {' | '}
            <Link to='/posts'>Posts</Link>
            <hr />

            {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Note: I'm rendering `Users` and `Posts` as children of react router's `Router` component.

---

### New Update

Ok, so the action is definitely reaching the reducer, and the reducer is definitely updating the redux store.

I now have it so that after the action is dispatched, the `Main` component's props are updated as desired, after the `Users` component has been mounted.

So, my problem is almost resolved. I think the issue now is one concerning `componentDidMount`. The response payload is making it's way to `Main` component props, but when I try to render the response the data, I get nothing.

**`Users` render function:**

```
{this.props.users ?
   this.props.users.map(user => <p>{user.name}</p>) :
   <p>No data</p>
}
```

All I'm getting is 'No data', and I don't know how to get the data returned in `componentDidMount` into my view.

I hope that's a bit clearer - apologies if not.

For the sake of full disclosure, here's my **reducer**:

```
const users = (state = [], action) => {
   switch(action.type) {
      case 'FETCH_REMOTE_DATA_SUCCESS' :
         if (action.response) {
            return action.response.data
         }
      default :
         return state;
   }
   return state;
}

export default users;
```

Comment: Are you passing `users` from Main to Users component? Can you post your `Main` component?

Comment: @azium, see update...

Comment: is `this.props.users` correct in your Main render function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... I have passed all props down to all children with the second argument as `this.props`, so any props will be accessible by the child routes, one of which renders `Users`.

Comment: It's not super clear in your question what the issue is. If you can say something like.. "I console logged the data here and it's correct, and I console logged the data here and its undefined" that would super helpful, or maybe you have a different problem all together

Comment: is this action: `FETCH_REMOTE_DATA_SUCCESS` making it successfully to your reducer? are you returning the correct thing there? i would post the reducer as well

Comment: @azium, apologies, if I could articulate the problem better I would :) Please see new update, hopefully this is getting closer to the solution and is a bit clearer...

Comment: From what I can tell, your users data is getting sent to App.js, but not your Users component. If you want the data to get pumped directly to Users, then you need to give it its own mapStateToProps to connect to Redux or pass it back down through App.

Comment: @EzraChang - I actually just spotted this. I'm attaching Main to a page that then conditionally renders different components depending on state. I forgot to pass `users` props from this page to the `Users` component. My method is probably not the most concise but its the best I can think of for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the correct data coming through `mapStateToProps` then you should see the correct data in `Main`, which means passing those props to `Users` should also work.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, { params }) => {
  console.log(state.users) <--- make sure this is correct

  const rootPage = params.rootPage || '';
  return {
    users: state.users,
    rootPage
   }
}
```

Then in Main:

```
render() {
  console.log(this.props.users) <--- make sure this is correct

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

If the above two steps log the incorrect data then something is up with reducers / actions (sounds like it's not, so good).

If those are correct and you're NOT getting the right data in Users component then the problem is with this line:

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
```

I think you *might* need to write that bit a differently, (not 100% sure though). I do a more comprehensive copy of props to my child routes

```
let children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
  return React.cloneElement(child, {
    ...child.props,
    ...this.props,
  })
})
```

Alternatively, you can `connect` your Users component which is probably a good idea anyways because it's the one that's actually using `users`

`connect(state => ({ users: state.users }))(Users)`

Comment: Don't know if you gave me the downvote... Actually the issue was I didn't successfully pass the props to `User`. Either way - your answer helped, and now it's resolved.